# how to determine which skewness is more strong?

Tags: math, statistics, histogram, probability

I have 6 sets of Data. I have used excel to produce the histogram. The histogram shows right skewness of the data. Now I have 6 histogram which are skewed to the right. The data are the duration taken for the execution of sorting and unsorting algorithm used in JAVA.

I need to determine which skewness is stronger in the case of these 6 histogram. How to determine the stronger case of skewness? Is the histogram with more longer tail on the right is more skewed?

Also a formula for skewness!

So many thanks.

Comment: have you tried the Excel skew function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracts from [Microsoft Office Support](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/skew-HP005209261.aspx)

> SKEW
>
> Returns the skewness of a distribution. Skewness characterizes the
>   degree of asymmetry of a distribution around its mean. Positive
>   skewness indicates a distribution with an asymmetric tail extending
>   toward more positive values. Negative skewness indicates a
>   distribution with an asymmetric tail extending toward more negative
>   values.
>
> Syntax
>
> SKEW(number1,number2,...)
>
> Number1, number2 ...     are 1 to 30 arguments for which you want to
>   calculate skewness. You can also use a single array or a reference to
>   an array instead of arguments separated by commas.
>
> The equation for skewness is defined as:

[image]

x bar will be the mean and s the standard deviation.